# Thymeleaf: handling maybe-existing properties of a model?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

**Problem:**
I have a Thymeleaf template in Spring MVC which I want to use for two things:
1) For **creating a new entity** in the database
2) For **updating an existing entity** in the database

There is only one tiny difference between those two use cases: The entity in the database has a **version** (optimistic locking) attribute set, so I want to remember this version as a hidden field in the template, which is easy to do.

To understand better where i am coming from here is my handler code for **creating a new entity**:

```
@GetMapping("/new") 
String showMapFormForAdd( Model model ) { 

    model.addAttribute( "map", null ); // PASS null into it 

    return "map-form"; // same template 
}
```

And here is the code for **updating an existing entity**:

```
@GetMapping("/{mapId}/update") 
public String showMapFormForUpdate( @PathVariable Long mapId, Model model ) { 

    GameMap map = mapService.findMap( mapId ); 

    model.addAttribute( "map", map ); // PASS the real map into it (with version!!!) 

    return "map-form"; // same template 
}
```

And here is the code for the **hidden version field in the Thymeleaf** template:

```
<input type="hidden" th:value="${map?.version}" name="version" />
```

However, when the template is rendered after the first handler (creating), I get an Exception, that the property version does not exist (its true, it doesn't exist).

**Question:**
How can I tell Thymeleaf, to only query the version and set it to value in the hidden field, only if the property `version` does exist in the "map" model which is injected into Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 1):

You can add conditional th:value

```
<input type="hidden" th:value="${map.version != null ? map.version : ''}" name="version" />
```